# How to control LabView VI front panel switches (on/off, bar adjuster) using Python scripts?

Tags: python, labview

I have a `LabView` front panel controlling switches and sensor voltage adjustors to the hardware and need to control these with a Python script. I do not have much knowledge of `LabView`. Please explain how this could be done.

Answer (score 4):

I found one reference on the LabVIEW discussion board that succeeded in [this](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Updating-Labview-exe-front-panel-from-python/m-p/711077#M325584), it uses the following code:

```
import win32com.client //load the interface
labview = win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application") //get a ref to the Labview application
VI = labview.getvireference(r'C:\TEMP\python.vi') //load the VI
VI.setcontrolvalue('Numeric','5') //set the control 'numeric' to 5
```

It seems like you need the win32com.client library in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can also push data between LabVIEW and Python using Mark E. Smith's excellent [XML-RPC package](http://lavag.org/files/file/66-xml-rpc-server-for-labview/).