# Read/Write LabView TDMS files in python under linux

Tags: python, linux, dll, labview

Does anyone know of a way to read and write the National Instruments binary file type (TDMS) in python under linux?  I know that NI has a C DLL available, but I don't know how to access that through python, or if I even can do so under linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like TDMS isn't directly supported under Linux (see [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/TDMS-on-Mac/td-p/547927)).

Your options currently are to use the [G-based functions directly in LabVIEW](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/6471) (It's possible that you can wrap them in a .so file), [calling LabVIEW from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524479/how-to-control-labview-vi-front-panel-switches-on-off-bar-adjuster-using-pytho), or building your own file parser from the [TDMS spec](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/5696).

Sorry, no really easy options.

**Edit:** It looks like there may be an open source project to try to do this at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytdms/.  Worth a try, at least.

Comment: I ended up using the pyTDMS project.  I had to fiddle with the LabView code in order to create the TDMS file in a way that pyTDMS could read it, but it worked perfectly after I got that going.

Comment: I had trouble reading my files with pyTDMS, but had more luck with npTDMS: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/npTDMS

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the python version 2.7 (thats the only one that is working with the tdms package for labview atleast)

```
Sudo pip install npTDMS
```

[Link to the tdms package page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/npTDMS)

and just follow the example on the page.